# how to decrypt a file that was encrypted with CryptoJs3+ library with custom iterations and key sizes, in openssl

Tags: javascript, encryption, openssl, aes, cryptojs

I have a text file that was encrypted by cryptojs(and maybe some custom js function to iterate the hash of the password) and I want to decrypt it in windows via openssl.exe not with a browser(which works flawlessly when i provide it with password). it looks like cryptojs has used some custom stuff like deriving key with sha512 and iterating it 11512 times as you see the js decryptor below and then uses evpkdf iteration 484 times(i have no idea what this stuff mean). the code snippet for decrypting the file from the cryptojs is below, i need the **openssl exe -cli params** to do so without using that js library in a browser.

```
function hex2a(t) { //hex to ascii
    for (var e = t.toString(), i = "", n = 0; n < e.length && "00" !== e.substr(n, 2); n += 2) i += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(e.substr(n, 2), 16));
    return i; }

    function decoder(secret, passwrd) {
        for (var i = CryptoJS.SHA512(passwrd), n = 0; n < 11512; n++) 
i = CryptoJS.SHA512(i);
        (CryptoJS.algo.AES.keySize = 32), 
(CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.iterations = 1e4), 
(CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.keySize = 32);
        var r = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(secret, i.toString());
        return (out = hex2a(r)), out;
    }
```

this is when it calls the function and returns the file if it was successfully decrypted.

```
var msg="base64 of the salted encrypted file via cryptojs"
function proceed() {
    var pass=document.getElementById('textfield2').value;
    a=decoder(msg, pass);
    if (a.search('{version')>-1) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML="SUCCESS";
        download("result.json",a);
    }   else {
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML="FAILED";
}
```

I have tried this(windows openssl.exe cli 1.1) and got an error about -iter and other param. dont know how to give it key size 32 and iteration  and evpkdf and hatever that js file does to decrypt.

```
OpenSSL.exe enc -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -d -pass pass:"simpletext" -in "tiny.bin" -out "result.txt"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code translation service. What have you tried and what were the issues?

Comment: @ArtjomB. my question is related to the hashtags I used and it was never asked before. i edited it anyway, added the params i used for openssl.

Comment: Oh, you mean the openssl commandline utility? That's not possible. You will have to write a bash script of similar to derive the key from the password with these custom values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decryption with OpenSSL is **principally not** possible for several reasons:

- The specified key size `AES.keySize = 32` defines a 128 bytes key (which is not passed directly here, but derived from a password). Presumably a 32 bytes key was intended, but CryptoJS specifies key sizes in words, where a word consists of 4 bytes.
  AES is only defined for 16/24/32 bytes keys, i. e. not for the 128 bytes key used. Although the key is invalid for AES, CryptoJS processes this key due to a bug ([Issue #293](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293)).
  From the key size the round number is derived directly, which results here to 38, ([source code](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/aes.js#L92)). However, AES is only defined for the round numbers 10 (AES-128), 12 (AES-192) and 14 (AES-256) ([AES, Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Security)). The generated ciphertext is therefore not AES compatible, i.e. decryption with an AES-compliant tool, in particular OpenSSL, is therefore generally impossible.
  For decryption with OpenSSL to be possible, `AES.keySize` needs to have one of the values 4/6/8, which corresponds to the permitted round numbers 10/12/14 or AES-128/192/256. The configuration `AES.keySize = 32` is therefore a KO criterion for all AES-compliant tools like OpenSSL.
- CryptoJS uses the OpenSSL function [`EVP_BytesToKey()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) for key derivation. However, the specified iteration count `EvpKDF.cfg.iterations = 1e4` is not supported by OpenSSL for key derivation with `EVP_BytesToKey()`, only the value `1` ([here, last part](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139)).
  More modern OpenSSL versions (from 1.1.1) have the option [*-iter*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html), but this is only used in conjunction with the key derivation PBKDF2, i.e. if *-iter* is specified, PBKDF2 is automatically used instead of `EVP_BytesToKey()`, which is not compatible with CryptoJS.
  For decryption to be possible with OpenSSL, `EvpKDF.cfg.iterations` would need to have the value `1`. The configuration `EvpKDF.cfg.iterations = 1e4` is therefore a KO criterion for OpenSSL.
- The password passed to CryptoJS is derived from the original password by multiple hashing with SHA512. As already explained in Artjom B.'s comment, this cannot be implemented with OpenSSL alone, but it would at least be possible as part of a script.
- The `EvpKDF.cfg.keySize` parameter has no effect on encryption/decryption and can be ignored.

If compatible values are used in the posted code instead of the incompatible values, e.g. `CryptoJS.algo.AES.keySize = 8` and `CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.iterations = 1`, decryption with OpenSSL is possible. The following example uses the posted code with compatible values and performs encryption and decryption. The ciphertext can be decrypted with OpenSSL:

```js
//
// Your code
//
function hex2a(t) {
    for (var e = t.toString(), i = "", n = 0; n < e.length && "00" !== e.substr(n, 2); n += 2) i += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(e.substr(n, 2), 16));
    return i; 
}

function decoder(secret, passwrd) {
    for (var i = CryptoJS.SHA512(passwrd), n = 0; n < 11512; n++) i = CryptoJS.SHA512(i);
    CryptoJS.algo.AES.keySize = 8;            // compatible with OpenSSL: 4/6/8, corresponds to AES-128/192/265
    CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.iterations = 1;  // compatible with OpenSSL: 1
    CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.keySize = 123;   // ignored
    var r = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(secret, i.toString());
    return (out = hex2a(r)), out;
}

// 
// The encryption counterpart
//
function encrypt(secret, passwrd) {
    for (var i = CryptoJS.SHA512(passwrd), n = 0; n < 11512; n++) i = CryptoJS.SHA512(i);
    CryptoJS.algo.AES.keySize = 8;
    CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.iterations = 1;
    CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.keySize = 456;
    console.log("CryptoJS input passphrase:\n", i.toString().replace(/(.{56})/g,'$1\n'));  
    var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(secret, i.toString());
    return ciphertext;
}

// 
// Encryption, decryption
//
var ciphertext = encrypt('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'my initial passphrase');
var decryptedData = decoder(ciphertext, 'my initial passphrase');
console.log("Ciphertext:\n", ciphertext.toString().replace(/(.{56})/g,'$1\n'));  
console.log("Plaintext:\n", decryptedData.replace(/(.{56})/g,'$1\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

with the possible output:

```
CryptoJS input passphrase: 7bff3331f9dcfbb2e1c5b6cb4170689db91fe5b12258d59672fe0e9ce61780c61f3e6dc324e58cc2170c6a8010083aafe07930708ee63c0022a7e9bce784c4c5
Ciphertext: U2FsdGVkX1/3SLTOsvc6CoWfg53rR+l//pHiWstJibl5D5OopIFWVmhUDhEpj7zBZRjA1vQiIoU2F5qR1v8NEw==
Plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

The ciphertext can be decrypted with the following OpenSSL statement (using the derived password directly):

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -A -in <path to ciphertext file> -md md5 -pass pass:7bff3331f9dcfbb2e1c5b6cb4170689db91fe5b12258d59672fe0e9ce61780c61f3e6dc324e58cc2170c6a8010083aafe07930708ee63c0022a7e9bce784c4c5
```

When using parameters different from these (e.g. `AES.keySize = 32` or `EvpKDF.cfg.iterations = 1e4`), decryption generally fails with *bad decrypt* (even when using `-iter 10000`).

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. so if i derive the sha512 of the passwords with custom iteration using another tool(powershell or python), is there any other program like openssl cli or a fork of it with extended features or maybe a windows cli version of cryptojs, or python library to help me decrypt my file in windows. (cli exe files are way faster than js files in browser) i dont know if nodejs can run a js function loop as fast as openssl.exe does.

Comment: @HamidHabibi - The 128 bytes key produces an encryption that does not comply with any standard, in particular not AES. Ultimately, this is a flawed encryption, which in all likelihood no other tool can decrypt (no matter in which language), i.e. a decryption is probably only possible with CryptoJS itself (it's of course possible to port the CryptoJS logic including the bug to another, faster language, but this requires a corresponding effort). NodeJS as CLI is possible, but unfortunately I don't have much experience here to help further or to estimate the performance.